# Show Label if button is clicked for certain time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a problem. I want to make a label pop up when button is clicked and it works, but I want it to make it again but with a different button. I did exactly the same in the working one and I edited to different conditions for the button you know and it doesn't work. Can somebody help me please? Thanks.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FullNameBOX.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage.Show();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else if(txtEmail.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage.Show();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else if(txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage.Show();
            timer1.Start(); 
        }
        else if(txtPassword2.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage.Show();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        timer1.Stop();
        ErrorMessage.Hide();
    }
    private void button4_Click_1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (FullnameBOX_Login.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage2.Show();
            timer2.Start();
        }
        else if(PasswordLogin.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorMessage2.Show();
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }
    
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        ErrorMessage2.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the Click handler of the second Button, does it get hit? You should investigate whether the second Button's Click event is actually wired up and why its handler is named `button4_Click_1` instead of `button4_Click` (manually added? Two *copies*?) -- Your code needs some care: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it up, assign meaningful names to your Controls - Also see the `ErrorProvider` and `ToolTip` components.

Comment: Every event like a button click or a timer event needs to be registered.  You can either register an event with a '+=' statement or do it automatically using the designer.  The designer only allows one event to be called by one object so when you need to have more than one object use the same event you need to do manually.  You can see example of the registering by opening the designer.cs file for the form.  You can move these registered events from the designer.cs file to your form.cs file.

Comment: Read jimi's comment carefully and try your goal. Modify the problem you encountered, and we will help you solve it next.